# Пересечение двух листов с разными объектами внутри

Tags: c#, linq

Всем привет.

Есть 2 коллекции:

`List<string>(keys)` и `PropertyInfo[](properties)`. Нужно найти пересечение `properties.Name` с `keys`.

Задача, которую решаю:

Получаю из INI-файла `List<string>(keys)` по указанной секции. Дальше из указанного дженерика получаю свойства, проверяю, какие `keys` совпадают с названиями свойств из `properties`, создаю экземпляр класса, вставляю данные из ini-файла в свойства и возвращаю из метода созданный класс.

Написанный код:

```
public T GetEntitiesBySection<T>(string section)
{ 
    var keys = GetKeys(section);
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite);

    foreach (var prop in properties) //вот здесь уже должны быть только те свойства, имена которых совпадают с keys
        prop.SetValue(instance, Read(section, prop.Name));

    return (T)instance;
}
```

Я помню про существование Intersect, но не могу понять, как работать с данный методом, когда внутри листов разные объекты. Конечно, можно сделать, `properties.Select(x => x.Name).Intersect(keys)`, но это вернёт `string`, а мне нужно `PropertyInfo`.

Конечно, можно с лёгкостью перебрать всё через цикл foreach и проблема решится, но хочется через linq

Comment: `properties  = properties.Where(p=>keys.Contains(p.Name));` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Точно! Спасибо. Оформите это в виде ответа? Я поставлю галочку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут не надо пересечения, достаточно просто фильтрации

```
properties  = properties.Where(p=>keys.Contains(p.Name)); ?
```